# How to find out which fonts are available in qml?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I would like to know which fonts I can use in a QML environment for the `font.family` property. Are these fonts system-specific or are they built into the framework? Is there any way to list all available fonts?

Comment: Please, do not provide an answer as an edit: post an answer to your question describing the newer solution found. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The fonts are system-specific so you should see what your system proposes.

If you are using **QtCreator** :

try putting your mouse over the end of your component name

```
Text <here> {
    ...
}
```

You should see a yellow light, click on it and you'll have an interface that allows to choose the font.

You can also access the interface with *ctrl + alt + space* while inside the component. Or with right click.

Answer (score 24):

This code will list all the accepted font families:

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent; 
    model: Qt.fontFamilies()

    delegate: Item {
        height: 40; 
        width: ListView.view.width
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: modelData; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: White color? In my case it resulted in invisible content.

Comment: It depends on the background that you use, yes change the color

Comment: See Gaël Porté's superb suggestion at the bottom to print the font names in the respective fonts.

Answer (score 4):

This is a system-specific list of fonts, but you can specify external font from resources (QRC)

Answer (score 3):

You can improve the previous answer by adding this

```
Text {
     font.family: modelData
     anchors.centerIn: parent
     text: modelData;
}
```